# How can one change the row height?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

With the new Table introduced in SwiftUI 3, how can one change the row height?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [ItemModel] = Array(0...100).map { ItemModel(title: "item \($0)") }
    @State private var selection = Set<ItemModel.ID>()

    var body: some View {
        Table(selection: $selection) {
            TableColumn("title", value: \.title)
        } rows: {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                TableRow(item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}
```

For the `TableColumn`, only a `width()` modifier is available. But for the `TableRow` one cannot specify the height. Is there really no way to provide the height for a `TableRow`?

Comment: It is not possible to specify something else than `TableRow`. You cannot have a custom body.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for changing the row height of a SwiftUI Table without doing any compromises. By changing the environment variable `.defaultMinListRowHeight`, the row height can be controlled easily.

Compared to the solution provided by @Mykel, this does not require the padding to be applied to each column and also placeholder rows that are shown when the table is empty will already have the specified height.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [ItemModel] = Array(0...100).map { ItemModel(title: "item \($0)") }
    @State private var selection = Set<ItemModel.ID>()

    var body: some View {
        Table(selection: $selection) {
            TableColumn("title", value: \.title)
        } rows: {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                TableRow(item)
            }
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 80)
    }
}

struct ItemModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}
```

Comment: If you check the date, `.defaultMinListRowHeight` clearly did not exist in macOS 12.  This is only macOS 13.x+.

Comment: Yes, I might have missed that. Don't know how you felt so offended by that.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is for macOS 12.x.  I have not tested how SwiftUI has progressed into macOS 13.x.

You can set the height with padding modifiers in the content of all TableColumns.  Then there is some limited styling you can do depending on the content (e.g. font on Text).

It's important to note the row will not adjust to content.

```
// For example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [ItemModel] = Array(0...100).map { ItemModel(title: "item \($0)") }
    @State private var selection = Set<ItemModel.ID>()

    var body: some View {
        Table(selection: $selection) {
            TableColumn("title") {
                Text("\($0.title)").padding(.vertical, 16) // <--- HERE
            }
        } rows: {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                TableRow(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works actually, but only when applied to every TableColumn. Seems not well designed from Apple.

Comment: @Yakuhzi I agree.  Introspecting into the code, I think they will add to it.  It seems like they simply removed features from this version of SwiftUI.